# The rounded corners of the images inside a card don't look right

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, rounded-corners

I have multiple cards with images inside those cards. I want the images to have rounded corners. The code kind of worked but the rounded corners don't look right.

[image: Unwanted result]

For the images, I'm just using the Bootstrap class `rounded`. The images are scaled down but not distorted. This is the CSS for the cards:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #E5E7EB;
  border-radius: 1rem; }
```

Simplified HTML:

```
    <div class="card border-0 p-3 p-md-3 p-lg-4 mb-3">
      <div class="row pb-4 text-left">
        <div class="col-1 ps-1">
          <h1 class="id-circle">B</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-11">
          <span class="description details-text pe-1">Text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row gy-3 mb-1 pb-0">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 pb-0">
          <div class="row pt-0 pb-0 image-row">
            <img class="rounded" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Any ideas of what could be happening? Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your CSS as-is. A simple `<div class="card">card</div>` shows nice rounded borders. Please post a [reprex] showing the unwanted result...

Comment: I edited my explanation. Please let me know if more info is needed @RenevanderLende

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below snippet: with your CSS and HTML, in both cases the bootstrap creates a small rounded corner of `4px` around the images using `.rounded { border-radius: .25rem !important }` (Firefox DevTools). In fact, with your HTML (second card), the rounded borders of the image are gone.

Still not showing the *unwanted* result you are experiencing. Something else in your CSS creates the result.

The odd border radius in the image is not reproducable on Stackoverflow with your code.

I added below CSS to override *bootstrap* `.rounded` in my Codepen test and got the same unwanted result. You must have done something similar. However, I still don't see it happening here on SO.

My [Codepen: SO74554098](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/vYrRzXY?editors=1100)

```css
.rounded {
    border-radius: 1rem !important;
}
```

The best option would, indeed, be to create a specific card layout for the images (as OP commented, 'card in a card') and use *bootstrap* `.rounded` or a custom class with `border-radius` set.

```css
.card {
  /* added for test */
  padding: 1rem; margin: 1rem; outline: 1px solid black;
  /**/
  
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 0.0625rem solid #e5e7eb;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.rounded {
  border-radius: 1rem !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<h3>only .card > .rounded</h3>
<div class="card">
  <img class="rounded" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200">
</div>

<h3>OP code with full bootstrap CSS (5.0.2)</h3>
<div class="card border-0 p-3 p-md-3 p-lg-4 mb-3">
  <div class="row pb-4 text-left">
    <div class="col-1 ps-1">
      <h1 class="id-circle">B</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-11">
      <span class="description details-text pe-1">Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row gy-3 mb-1 pb-0">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 pb-0">
      <div class="row pt-0 pb-0 image-row">
        <img class="rounded" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This totally helped me. As I override the bootstrap .rounded I get the unwanted result. So the solution was to make each image a card within the big card.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

`border-radius: 25px;`

sometimes rem doesn't work for border radius

Comment: It is not the `rem` unit that gives strange results, it's usually the wrong value used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).